# How to have a AngularJS directive update the anchors generated by another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and not sure I am wording my question properly.  Here is the issue.  I receive a block of html from a database with all tags included

```
<DOCTYPE>
 <html>
     <head>...</head>
     <body>...</body>
 </html>
```

It can't be helped, I don't have control over anything in the DB, this is what I receive and have to work with.

My angular code to render this info in a kendo grid.  I created directives to write render the HTML in a specific column in my grid.

```
myDirectives.directive('column', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '=',
            text: '=',
        },
        replace: true,
        template: <div><span target-blank>[template html to render to column in the grid]</span></div>,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // code to do stuff 
        }
    }
}
```

I also created another directive:

```
myDirectives.directive('target-blank', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        compile: function (element) {
            var elems = (element.prop("tagName") === 'A') ? element : element.find('a');
            elems.attr("target", "_blank");
        }
    };
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to check every anchor in the returned HTML and make the anchors open in a new window.  The columns HTML render perfectly with no issue, however, the anchors still keep opening in the same tab and not in a new tab.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.

UPDATE 1: @dfsq, Here is a link  of your test that I updated [http://plnkr.co/edit/WVkLDjhAzRxuS1A7mPg0?p=preview]  I tried using the ng-bind-html here but it is throwing errors.  It works for me in my code though.

Comment: Are you trying to change _all_ anchor tags? If so you should just write a directive for `a` instead.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, I am trying to change all the a tags within the span only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the second directive was firing as soon as the page loaded and not giving time for kendo to render the html.  It was purely a timing issue.  Adding $timeout dependency solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define directive `target-blank` you need to follow camelCase notation in JS:

```
myDirectives.directive('targetBlank', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        compile: function (element) {
            var elems = (element.prop("tagName") === 'A') ? element : element.find('a');
            elems.attr("target", "_blank");
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: that still didn't work, they anchors are still opening in the same tab

Comment: Well directive is fine with this fix (demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4wVjNXpPtxK0kvXxYmpI?p=preview) so probably something else on your end. Can you make a demo?

Comment: Seems the issue is somewhere with the Kendo UI Grid rendering the directive template and then using the anchor directive.  When I try to view the element.find('a').attr("href") it is coming across as undefined.  Is there a way to make the anchor directive load after the first is rendered in the kendo grid?

Comment: Probably yes. Can you set up a simple demo, it's just much simpler to experiment.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to.  The data being built from the first directive is coming from a database.  I am not sure how to mimic that.

Comment: Just use some variable like if it came from database: `$scope.html = '<div><a href="http://google.com">Some</a></div>'` and insert this context in the grid.

Comment: Here is a link  of your test that I updated [http://plnkr.co/edit/WVkLDjhAzRxuS1A7mPg0?p=preview]  I tried using the ng-bind-html here but it is throwing errors.  It works for me in my code though.

Comment: @C.Daniel If you use ngBindHtml then you also need to make your directive to process links in another digest (after content is inserted). http://plnkr.co/edit/atGFW4TPZ2z1wOdLJypy?p=preview

Comment: What do you mean (in another digest)?  This data is coming from the DB and not something I enter.  I don't follow what you mean by another digest after content is inserted.  I'm using a Kendo UI Grid so I don't really touch the data at all but pass it into Kendo which renders the directive with the data.

Comment: Just try the directive in the demo I posted with your kendo grid and tell me if it works.

Comment: Here is my update but I cannot get the grid to show [http://plnkr.co/edit/3K2Gnejct4aJnS7tMD3v?p=preview]

Comment: You should use kendo grid angular directive. Not just jQuery version.

Comment: I honestly have no clue how to make that work in plnkr.  I tried adding the CDN's to kendo ui but keep getting errors.  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.